# How can i get unique value with the lowest price in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have stuck with issue in this array can any one please help me

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 41
        [make] => Maruti Suzuki
        [model] => Alto 800
        [variant] => LXI
        [variantid] => 2628
        [city] => Mumbai
        [car_price] => 321279
        [img] => maruti-suzuki-alto-800-default-transparent.png
    )


[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 38
        [make] => Maruti Suzuki
        [model] => Alto 800
        [variant] => Lx
        [variantid] => 2627
        [city] => Mumbai
        [car_price] => 298655
        [img] => maruti-suzuki-alto-800-default-transparent.png
    )

 )
```

Here my issue is i need to get the only one alto 800 with which is having lowest price, please suggest me any one

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried something on your own ... show us the code

Comment: I think better option is to optimize your query... !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**array_multisort**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) (PHP 4, PHP 5) and [**array_map**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (PHP 4 >= 4.0.6, PHP 5)

```
// Sort your array in ascending order
array_multisort(array_map(function($_){return $_["car_price"];},$array), SORT_ASC, $array);

// To get array of min car price
print_r($array[0]);

// To get only car price
echo $array[0]["car_price"];
```

If you have **PHP 5 >= 5.5.0** then use [**array_column**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
array_multisort(array_column($array,"car_price"), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

**Test**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php 
<?php

$array = array( 
              array(
                   "id"=>41,
                   "make"=>"Maruti Suzuki",
                   "model"=>"Alto 800",
                   "variant"=>"LXI",
                   "variantid"=>2628,
                   "city"=>"Mumbai",
                   "car_price"=>321279,
                   "img"=>"maruti-suzuki-alto-800-default-transparent.png"
                  ),
             array(
                   "id"=>38,
                   "make"=>"Maruti Suzuki",
                   "model"=>"Alto 800",
                   "variant"=>"Lx",
                   "variantid"=>2627,
                   "city"=>"Mumbai",
                   "car_price"=>298655,
                   "img"=>"maruti-suzuki-alto-800-default-transparent.png"
                  ),
              );

array_multisort(array_map(function($_){return $_["car_price"];},$array), SORT_ASC, $array);

// To get array of min car price
print_r($array[0]);

// To get only car price
echo $array[0]["car_price"];

?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [id] => 38
    [make] => Maruti Suzuki
    [model] => Alto 800
    [variant] => Lx
    [variantid] => 2627
    [city] => Mumbai
    [car_price] => 298655
    [img] => maruti-suzuki-alto-800-default-transparent.png
)
298655
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, though note that it is not optimized:

```
<?php
$min_price=9999999;
$best_deal=array();
foreach($array as $car){
    if($car['model']=="Alto 800" && $car['price']<$min_price){
        $min_price=$car['price'];
        $best_deal=$car;
    }
}

?>
```

The cheapest car will be in the variable `$best_deal`, if it is not an empty `array` (in which case it means all prices are above **9999999** or your `$array` is **empty**)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper array and use min function

```
<?php
$tmp = []; // or $tmp = array() depending on how recent your PHP version is
foreach($cars as $car) {
    $tmp[] = $car['car_price'];
}
$lowest = min($tmp);
foreach($cars as $car) {
    if($car['car_price'] == $lowest) {
        // Your car is now $car
    }
}
?>
```

Note, if you have more than 1 car with the same price, the first one in the array would be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  PHP 5.3 try with usort

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['car_price'] - $b['car_price'];
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray[0] );
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to let you in on a little secret...

```
SELECT id, make, model, variant, variantid, city, car_price, img
    FROM sometable
    ORDER BY car_price ASC;
```

Now you don't have to sort in PHP at all :)